# How to extract / subset an element from a list with the magrittr %>% pipe?

Tags: r, magrittr

Since the introduction of the `%>%` operator in the `magrittr` package (and it's use in `dplyr`), I have started to use this in my own work.

One simple operation has me stumped, however.  Specifically, this is the extraction (or subsetting) of elements from a list.

An example: In base R I would use `$`, `[` or `[[` to extract an element from a list:

```
iris$Species
iris[["Species"]]
```

I can achieve the same using the `%>%` pipe:

```
iris %>%
  subset(select = "Species") %>%
  head

  Species
1  setosa
2  setosa
3  setosa
4  setosa
5  setosa
6  setosa
```

Or

```
iris %>%
  `[[`("Species") %>%
  levels

[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

However, this feels like a messy, clunky solution.

**Is there a more elegant, canonical way to extract an element from a list using the `%>%` pipe?**

Note: I don't want any solution involving `dplyr`, for the simple reason that I want the solution to work with any R object, including lists and matrices, not just data frames.

Comment: use use_series, extract2 and extract for $, [[, [, respectively. To see a list of the aliases, execute e.g. ?multiply_by.

Comment: @Bangyou That's great.  I didn't know that.  Do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: Side comment: take a look at `pipeR` , as it has slightly different capabilities from `magrittr`

Comment: Actually, your "messy" solution iris %>% `[[`("Species") is exactly the solution I was looking for. In my case, I use dplyr, and don't want to load magrittr in addition, so that works for me!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In v 1.5 of magrittr on CRAN you can use the `%$%` operator:

```
iris %$% 
  Species %>%
  levels
```

It is essentially a wrapper around `with` but nicer than

```
iris %>% 
  with(Species %>% levels)
```

or

```
iris %>%
  with(Species) %>%
  levels
```

It is designed to be convinient when functions don't have their own data argument, e.g. with plot you can do

```
iris %>% 
  plot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .)
```

but e.g. with `ts.plot` you can't do that, so now:

```
iris %$%
  ts.plot(Sepal.Length)
```

[yeah, I know the example makes no sense, but it illustrates the point]

Note also that `[<-` and `[[<-` also have aliases, `inset` and `inset2`..

Answer (score 38):

Use `use_series`, `extract2` and `extract` for `$`, `[[`, `[`, respectively.

```
?extract
```

> magrittr provides a series of aliases which can be more pleasant to
>   use when composing chains using the `%>%` operator."

For your example, you could try

```
iris %>%
  extract("Species")
```

and

```
iris %>%
  extract2("Species") %>%
  levels
```

See the bottom of this page for more: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html

Answer (score 8):

A more recent `tidyverse` solution: `pluck()` from `purrr` (since 0.2.3) extracts a named element from a list (or a named column from a data frame):

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  pluck("Species")
```

Note: to access the element by index number, you can also use `first()`, `last()` or `nth()` from `dplyr` on any object (list, data frame, matrix) to extract its first, last or nth element:

```
iris %>% 
  as.list() %>%  # unnecessary, just to show it works on lists too
  last()         # or nth(5) in this case, to get Species
```

Comment: Did not know about first, last, or nth. These are super helpful, thank you!