# Issue with piping and rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, piping

I'm trying to scrape options prices from the [ASX](http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/optionPrices.do?by=underlyingCode&underlyingCode=CBA&expiryDate=&optionType=B) with rvest and I'd like some help piping my code. I want to **pipe and end up with a data frame**.

The page at the link above has two tables, the first with share price information and the second with all options. When I run the following code I get a dataframe of the second table:

```
html <- read_html("http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/optionPrices.do?by=underlyingCode&underlyingCode=ANZ&expiryDate=&optionType=B")
nodes <- html_nodes(html, "table.options")
df <- html_table(nodes)[[2]]
```

But when I try to pipe that same code with the following:

```
html <- read_html("http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/optionPrices.do?by=underlyingCode&underlyingCode=ANZ&expiryDate=&optionType=B")
html %>% 
 html_nodes("table.options") %>% 
 html_table()[[2]]
```

I get an error reading 'Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "NULL"'

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100678/how-to-extract-subset-an-element-from-a-list-with-the-magrittr-pipe)

Comment: At least have the decency to inform potential answerers that you're willing to put them at risk of civil & criminal penalties for your financial gain. http://www.asx.com.au/about/terms-use.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to index that directly you would have to index in a seperate pipe like so

```
read_html("http://www.asx.com.au/asx/markets/optionPrices.do?by=underlyingCode&underlyingCode=ANZ&expiryDate=&optionType=B") %>%
html_nodes("table.options") %>%
html_table() %>%
.[[2]]
```

where `.` acts as the output of the previous pipe.